# How to save file in cache directory and view them in android?

Tags: android, file, caching

I am saving file in cache directory(file can be any attachment). But when

I view it using Action_view it is showing Black screen. If I view any pdf file, it is showing error message "cannot open pdf file"

```
  @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            try {
    File dir = new File(getBaseContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
    File tempFile = new File(dir + "/" + FILE_LOCATION);

    if (!tempFile .exists()) {
                        tempFile.mkdirs();
                    }
    String fname = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/"));
                    File file1 = new File(tempFile , fname);

    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                        connection.connect();

     int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file1);

    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                        long total = 0;
                        int count;
                        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                            total += count;

                            // Publish the progress
                            publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / fileLength));
                            output.write(data, 0, count);
                        }

                        output.close();
                        input.close();
}
 catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
 return "Download complete.";
        }


 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(EnableNotificationDemo.this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading, Please Wait!");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
}

 @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

To view this saved file.. I am using code of Action_view of this link ...
http://www.androidsnippets.com/open-any-type-of-file-with-default-intent.html

If I save file in Internal storage and then view it, it is working properly.
but I want to save it in cache directory...

Thanks in advance....

Comment: can you see your file created properly? use Device File Explorer of Android Studio.

Comment: yes I have seen all the files are downloaded.... @user1506104

Comment: and which pdf viewer are you using to view your file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android cant open pdf from cache dir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748218/android-cant-open-pdf-from-cache-dir)

Comment: @user1506104: drive pdf viewer

Comment: but it is working if I view file stored in internal storage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167252/discussion-between-pragya-mendiratta-and-user1506104).